# How to bind an Objective-C static library to Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I have read the documentation from Xamarin.

And this is my test class in Objective-C:

```
#import "XamarinBundleLib.h"

@implementation XamarinBundleLib

+(NSString *)testBinding{
    return @"Hello Binding";
}
@end
```

It's very easy, just one method.

And this is my C# class:

```
namespace ResloveName
{
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface IXamarinBundleLib {
        [Static,Export ("testBinding")]
        NSString TestBinding {get;}
    }
}
```

Then this is my AppDelegate code:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

            string testStr = ResloveName.IXamarinBundleLib.TestBinding.ToString ();
            System.Console.WriteLine ("testStr="+testStr);

            return true;
        }
```

When I run the application, I get this exception:
[image]

The TestBinding attributes is null.
I must be wrong somewhere, so how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try Objective Sharpie ?

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/

Comment: Try binding using `string` and not `NSString`. If that doesn't work, it's most likely that the native library wasn't linked into the executable for some reason (a build log would show this).

Comment: I've trying to use string instead of NSString, but that is not right as well. Now I think maybe some thing wrong with my native library too, I will check it. Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a very detailed blog post about creating a static library from ObjC code last year that works on Xamarin.iOS binding projects and you can find it [here](http://alexsoto.me/bindings-bindings-bindings-part1/) (just in case :wink::wink:).

That being said if you already have a fat static library in your hands and it is already added into your Xamarin.iOS Binding Project as shown here:

[image: binding image]

The issue could be that your `libxyz.linkwith.cs` is missing some information, if it looks like this:

```
using ObjCRuntime;
[assembly: LinkWith ("libFoo.a", SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true)]
```

it is definitely missing some important information about the architectures supported by your fat library (it is missing the second argument `target`), you can use the following command to retrieve what architectures your current static library supports

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info path/to/your/libFoo.a
```

and you should get something like this as output

```
Architectures in the fat file: Foo/libFoo.a are: i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64
```

So we know this static library supports `i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64` and we should provide our `LinkWith` attribute the supported archs by providing the second argument `target` as follows:

```
using ObjCRuntime;
[assembly: LinkWith ("libFoo.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Arm64 | LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.Simulator64, SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true)]
```

Also make sure that the first parameter of the `LinkWith` attribute matches your static library file name ("libFoo.a" in my case).

---

The other thing I would suggest double checking is that the `Build Action` of your static library (`libFoo.a` in my case) is correctly set to `ObjcBindingNativeLibrary` as show here:

[image: binding image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sorry for answer too late. It's very helpful, thanks.

Comment: You can mark this as the answer if it solved your issue :) glad it helped you

Comment: @dalexsoto your blog post seems offline, can I find it somewhere else?