# Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class Xamarian

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin Studio to build iOS app.

But I am getting this weird builds with follow error.

**Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: PayPalTouch. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalTouch' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211)**

**Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202)**

Trying many ways following the stack overflow discussions. But still no good!

Any idea how can i fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I fixed similar issues by adding a [Protocol] tag before every classes in error.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/registrar/

Answer (score -2):

I have no experience with using Xamarin Studio, can't find the detial, but there is a question I asked about How to link an Objective-C static library to Xamarin.iOS, you can take a look.

[How to bind an Objective-C static library to Xamarin.iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733584/how-to-bind-an-objective-c-static-library-to-xamarin-ios)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Not relevant to the questions

Comment: So sorry about that, I means that I have no experience like you point when using XS. It seems like that you are using a PayPal SDK, so I just hope could give you some advice about binding native library.@techhunter