# How do I call an IOS library in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I have NeoSpeech library (text to speech) for IOS having .a , .h & database files. This library is working fine in ios . Now i have to consume this library in Xamarin project. I am trying to consume using static library but it is not possible to call a library inside other so i am not able to use neospeech library inside static library. There is another option in xamarin i.e. Native C linking with xamarin but there is no proper documentation for this. Also is it good to use Linking Native Libraries in my scanrio. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Objective Sharpie](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/advanced/) it takes **header files** (not .a file) and produces C# api definition files: ApiDefinition.cs and StructAndEnums.cs. Sometimes depend on you h files it generates only StructAndEnums. It may be ok, but if it isn't sharpie should report some errors that you can search over SO.

Then you can create Binding project refer .a file there and generated ApiDefinitions. If you have separate .a for different processor architectures you can make FAT-library in Mac OS bash using `lipo` and refer only fat lib. For yours libs it'll be:

```
lipo -create libvt_eng_james_univ.a, libvt_eng_james_armv77s64.a libvt_eng_beth_simulation.a -output lib_eng_james_fat.a
```

May be libvt_eng_james_univ.a is already fat, You can check it by

```
lipo -info libvt_eng_james_univ.a
```

It'll show you all architectures in fat lib: i386 x86_64 for simulator armv7, armv7s arm64 for device.

After that just refer this binding project from you main Xamarin project as simple library proj. And then you can use all classes just like from other libraries.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually there are three library files (libvt_eng_james_univ.a, libvt_eng_james_armv77s64.a and libvt_eng_beth_simulation.a). I have tried Objective Sharpie for univ.a file. It only creates StructsAndEnums.cs file and there is no Apidefinition file. The code inside StructsAndEnums is:
static class CFunctions
 {
// extern void VT_UNLOADTTS_ENG_James (int nSpeakerID); 
[DllImport ("__Internal")]  
[Verify (PlatformInvoke)] 
static extern void VT_UNLOADTTS_ENG_James (int nSpeakerID);
}
Please let me know how to call this methods in Xamarin projects.

Comment: Also do I need to create fat library by combining all three libraries files (libvt_eng_james_univ.a, libvt_eng_james_armv77s64.a and libvt_eng_beth_simulation.a) or is it work with libvt_eng_james_univ.a.

Comment: @Tarlok you should use header files with sarpie, not library. It will analyze definition of public classes and methods and generate c# definitions for them. 

Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used header file (.h) that generate above code and then added univ.a file in my project. Header file not generating apidefination.cs file. There is only  StructsAndEnums.cs file. Do I missing something?

Comment: @Tarlok check for errors in output and search for them on SO.

Comment: Thanks of the your help. I have called the StructsAndEnums.cs methods in code and made some changes in path. Everything is working fine. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Tarlok if answer helped you, please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have the same problem with me, check my question, there is a wonderful answer for link Objective-C's library to Xamarin.

[How to bind an Objective-C static library to Xamarin.iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733584/how-to-bind-an-objective-c-static-library-to-xamarin-ios)

Hope it can help you.